# Is there a similar solution to get WOL to work on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: hp, wakeonlan

I have an HP EliteBook and am trying to enable Wake-on-Lan but I was not able to get it to work. The BIOS doesn't have a WOL setting.

I did some searching and found this link: https://support.hp.com/ro-en/document/c04955641. My laptop is listed here. Is there a similar process I can follow on Ubuntu 20.04?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really it is possible by using `ethtool` application. I have just tested below method on Marvell 88E8057. For me it allows to wake device from suspend, your result may be different.

You have to run the command similar to

```
sudo ethtool -s eth2 wol g
```

where:

- `eth2` is a logical name of Ethernet interface (consult with `lshw -C network` for exact name in your system);
- `wol`

  > Sets Wake-on-LAN options.  Not all devices support this.  The argument to this option is a string of characters specifying which options  to  en                  able.
  >
  > - `p`   Wake on PHY activity
  > - `u`   Wake on unicast messages
  > - `m`   Wake on multicast messages
  > - `b`   Wake on broadcast messages
  > - `a`   Wake on ARP
  > - **`g`**   Wake on MagicPacket™
  > - `s`   Enable SecureOn™ password for MagicPacket™
  > - `d`   Disable  (wake  on  nothing).   This option clears all previous options.

For details consult with `man ethtool` locally or [online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man8/ethtool.8.html).